# Determine the space base

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Determine the base space ***S*** of all solutions to the equation system =

\begin{cases}
1q +2w +7e-9r+31t =0 \\
2q +4w+ 7e-11r+34t =0\\
3q+6w+5e-11r+29t=0 \\
\end{cases}

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccccc|c}
      1&2&7&-9&31&0\\
      2&4&7&-11&34&0\\
      3&6&5&-11&29&0
    \end{array}
\right] $$

I'm not really sure what is the question about... I've already made:
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccccc|c}
      1&2&0&-2&3&0\\
      0&0&1&-1&4&0\\
      0&0&0&-0&0&0
    \end{array}
\right] $$

so:

\begin{cases}
q=-2w+2r-3t \\
e=r-4t\\
\end{cases}

So what should I give as answer? ***w,r*** and ***t***?

Answer (score 0):

So the set 
S = { $ \lambda * (-2, 1, 0, 0, 0) + \mu * (2, 0, 1, 1, 0) + \nu * (-3, 0, 0, 0, 1) $ } is the space of the solutions.

Now go from here and try determining a basis for S.

Comment: More directly, to get the 3 basis vectors,take in turn each of the independent variables *w*, *r*, *t* to be 1 and the other two to be 0.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I did ? But you still have to consider the dependent variables q and e. Sorry if my notation is a bit unclear. But it's supposed to be in that order (q,w,e,r,t)

Comment: I was just indicating one does not have to explicitly form the nullspace, as you did, in order to list a basis for it. Yes, put the variables in the order $(q, w, e, r, t)$ -- or any permutation of them that's convenient. Then assign 1 to one of the (in this case, 3) independent variables (here $w$, $r$, $t$) and 0 to the other independent variables, calculating the resulting values of the dependent variables ($q$ and $e$), and form the corresponding vector of these values. It's just a shortcut that works in general.

Comment: Ok year, I can see what you mean. Thing is I wanted to give more of a hint and not the solution itself, your way is much easier though if one already knows how to work with vectorspaces/bases/etc